# Асинхронная загрузка на angularjs

Tags: ajax, javascript, асинхронность, angularjs

Добрый день.
Делаю ajax на angularjs, но он получается синхронный, и подвисает сайт.
Пример:

```
$http.get('api/getstudents').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.Students= data;
    });
```

Как сделать его асинхронным и выводить сначала элемент `<div>Загрузка...</div>`, а по окончании скрыть?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так в чем то проблема? Метод get - он асинхронный, то есть уже решает задачу.

темплейт

```
<div> {{ data }} </div>
```

код

```
$scope.data = "Загрузка";
$http.get('api/getstudents').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.data = data;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Запрос асинхронный, и сайт целиком подвисать не должен. Ну а для того чтобы показать надпись "загрузка...", пока не загрузились данные, можете воспользоваться директивами [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) или [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

```
<div ng-hide="Students">Загрузка...</div>
<div ng-repeat="student in Students">{{student.name}}</div>
```

Как-то так.